# How to get category Id/name in shopping-cart.tpl in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, categories, product

I need to show some fields for some particular category ,so I need to know the category in shopping-cart.tpl. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fetch from `$cart` variable